# store a blob string in database table

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-blob-storage

Hi I'm new to azure storage blob. I have a project in WPF and I have created a container in azure storage blob that I can send /upload images to on button click. Can anyone tell me if I can store a string form the blob into my sql database that will allow me to access/use/display the image in my WPF project.

Maybe someone could direct me to an example! Thanks!

```
    private void btnSAVE_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] photo = GetPhoto(filePath);

            sc.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Rewards (Name, Picture,  ) values'" + txtName.Text+ "','" + txtPicture.Text + "')", sc);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Picture", SqlDbType.Image, photo.Length).Value = photo;


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted");

            sc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        displayAll();

    }

    private byte[] GetPhoto(string filePath)        {
              {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        byte[] photo = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        br.Close();
        fs.Close();

        return photo;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store URL of that blob and  use that URL to display image

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob();
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path + "/" + up.GetName().ToString()))
{
      blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
string URL = blockBlob.Uri.OriginalString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link [Writing BLOB values to a database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
From MSDN:

> To write a BLOB value to your database, issue the appropriate INSERT
>   or UPDATE statement and pass the BLOB value as an input parameter. If
>   your BLOB is stored as text, such as a SQL Server text field, you can
>   pass the BLOB as a string parameter. If the BLOB is stored in binary
>   format, such as a SQL Server image field, you can pass an array of
>   type byte as a binary parameter.